# Ramifications and Impacts to Users when Detaching TFS Database

Tags: database, team-foundation-server

I have a scenario where I have to detach for a backup and then reattach the database from Team Foundation Server 2017. Our database administrator said that there would be an impact to users online that would prevent the detachment from occurring if they were doing a specific activity, can you advise? I have been asked to find out what the users to do and prepare for when we do the detachment. How will this impact the TFS and user processes?

Please advise and thank you.

Comment: Why would you do this? There are a number of ways to backup a SQL database without detaching it.

Answer (score 1):

The collection is unavailable. Meaning, people can't access this code repositories, package feeds, work items etc. When using TFVC server workspaces this will take local copies of code offline, increasing the chances of merge conflicts. Any tools and service hooks will be unavailable too.

To prepare users can:

- check in their changes.
- make sure they have the latest versions of files in their workspace to minimize chances of merge conflicts while working offline.
- switch their tfvc workspaces to local for better offline support.
- perform a fetch in Git, if they're using git.
- turn off tools, scheduled tasks, jobs etc that poll the collection.

Detach is a impactfull operation, it replicates a lot of data from the configuration database and Active Directory to the collection database. In case detach fails, a full server restore is required.

The ideal solution is to restore a recent standard backup to a 2nd (set of) servers and perform the detach there. That has zero user impact.